# How do I improve performance on a DISTINCT select across three joined tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, inner-join, distinct

I have the following tables in question:

- Personas
- ImpressionsPersonas  [join table - Personas ManyToMany Impressions]
- Impressions

My query looks like this, the EXPLAIN results are attached below:

```
   SELECT

   DISTINCT (Personas.id),
    Personas.parent_id, 
   Personas.persona, 
   Personas.subpersonas_count, 
   Personas.is_subpersona, 
   Personas.impressions_count, 
   Personas.created, 
   Personas.modified


   FROM personas as Personas 

   INNER JOIN   
        impressions_personas ImpressionsPersonas ON (
        Personas.id = ImpressionsPersonas.persona_id
    )
   inner JOIN impressions Impressions ON (Impressions.id = ImpressionsPersonas.impression_id AND Impressions.timestamp >= "2016-06-01 00:00:00" AND Impressions.timestamp <= "2016-07-31 00:00:00")
```

**EXPLAIN**

```
    +----+-------------+---------------------+--------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------+---------+---------------------------------------------+------+----------+-----------------------+
    | id | select_type | table               | type   | possible_keys                                                         | key         | key_len | ref                                         | rows | filtered | Extra                 |
    +----+-------------+---------------------+--------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------+---------+---------------------------------------------+------+----------+-----------------------+
    |  1 | SIMPLE      | Personas            | ALL    | PRIMARY                                                               | NULL        | NULL    | NULL                                        |  159 |   100.00 | Using temporary       |
    |  1 | SIMPLE      | ImpressionsPersonas | ref    | impression_idx,persona_idx,comp_imp_persona,comp_imp_pri,comp_per_pri | persona_idx | 8       | gen1_d2go.Personas.id                       |  396 |   100.00 | Distinct              |
    |  1 | SIMPLE      | Impressions         | eq_ref | PRIMARY,timestamp,timestamp_id                                        | PRIMARY     | 8       | gen1_d2go.ImpressionsPersonas.impression_id |    1 |   100.00 | Using where; Distinct |
    +----+-------------+---------------------+--------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------+---------+---------------------------------------------+------+----------+-----------------------+
    3 rows in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

**CREATE STATEMENT FOR PERSONAS**

```
CREATE TABLE `personas` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `parent_id` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `persona` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `subpersonas_count` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT '0',
  `is_subpersona` tinyint(1) unsigned DEFAULT '0',
  `impressions_count` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT '0',
  `created` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `modified` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `lookup` (`parent_id`,`persona`),
  KEY `parent_index` (`parent_id`),
  KEY `persona` (`persona`),
  KEY `persona_a_id` (`id`,`persona`),
  CONSTRAINT `self_referential_join_to_self` FOREIGN KEY (`parent_id`) REFERENCES `personas` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1049 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

**CREATE STATEMENT FOR IMPRESSIONS_PERSONAS**

```
CREATE TABLE `impressions_personas` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `impression_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `persona_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `created` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `modified` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `impression_idx` (`impression_id`),
  KEY `persona_idx` (`persona_id`),
  KEY `comp_imp_persona` (`impression_id`,`persona_id`),
  KEY `comp_imp_pri` (`impression_id`,`id`),
  KEY `comp_per_pri` (`persona_id`,`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `impression` FOREIGN KEY (`impression_id`) REFERENCES `impressions` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `persona` FOREIGN KEY (`persona_id`) REFERENCES `personas` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=19387839 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

**CREATE STATEMENT FOR IMPRESSIONS**

```
CREATE TABLE `impressions` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `device_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `beacon_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `zone_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `application_id` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `timestamp` datetime NOT NULL,
  `google_place_id` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(60) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lat` decimal(15,10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lng` decimal(15,10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `personas_count` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT '0',
  `created` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `modified` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `device_idx` (`device_id`),
  KEY `zone_idx` (`zone_id`),
  KEY `beacon_id_idx2` (`beacon_id`),
  KEY `timestamp` (`timestamp`),
  KEY `appid_fk_idx_idx` (`application_id`),
  KEY `comp_lookup` (`device_id`,`beacon_id`,`timestamp`),
  KEY `timestamp_id` (`timestamp`,`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `appid_fk_idx` FOREIGN KEY (`application_id`) REFERENCES `applications` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `beacon_id` FOREIGN KEY (`beacon_id`) REFERENCES `beacons` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `device2` FOREIGN KEY (`device_id`) REFERENCES `devices` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `zone_FK` FOREIGN KEY (`zone_id`) REFERENCES `zones` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1582724 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

---

Now - when I run the query without the DISTINCT and using a `COUNT(*)`, it pulls about 17,000,000 records. Running it with DISTINCT yields 112 records. I am not sure why there are so many records showing up when the explain showed only 159 and 396.

Some information about the tables:

The Personas table contains 159 records. The ImpressionsPersonas table contains about 12.6 million, and Impressions contains about 920,000 records.

What we are doing is selecting the `Personas` table and joining to the Impressions by way of the join table `ImpressionsPersonas`. There are filters applied to the `Impressions` table (date in this case).

Note: removing the date filter had a negligible impact on the execution time - which hovers right around 120s. Is there a way to filter these records down to cut down the execution time of this query?

Comment: Would changing the whole joining into `IN` or something help? Not sure how the engine handles things but it seems a bit pointless to join and distinct when you're actually just finding unique IDs and then getting those few records from the personas table.

Comment: Something in the lines of `select * from personas where id in (select distinct(persona_id) from impressions_personas inner JOIN impressions Impressions ON Impressions.id = ImpressionsPersonas.impression_id AND Impressions.timestamp >= "2016-06-01 00:00:00" AND Impressions.timestamp <= "2016-07-31 00:00:00"))`. Also not sure if group by is any different from DISTINCT

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen well - since there is a join table, it results in duplicate records being returned, hence the need for the distinct selection.

Comment: @BarryChapman Yes, but when you do the distinct/group by *first* and then select the actual rows you want it might be very different. You don't need to join three tables, you join two and get the few IDs to select the end results with.

Comment: DISTINCT is not a function. It takes no arguments. Your parentheses serve no purpose (except to confuse)

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen - that did exactly what I needed. If you want to create an answer, i will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume that you want to get the list of persons who have at least 1 impression within a specified time period. To get this, you can use such a correlated sub-query:

```
SELECT
   Personas.id,
   Personas.parent_id, 
   Personas.persona, 
   Personas.subpersonas_count, 
   Personas.is_subpersona, 
   Personas.impressions_count, 
   Personas.created, 
   Personas.modified

   FROM personas as Personas 
   WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM impressions_personas 
       LEFT JOIN impressions Impressions ON 
           Impressions.id = ImpressionsPersonas.impression_id 
       WHERE Personas.id = ImpressionsPersonas.persona_id
           AND Impressions.timestamp >= "2016-06-01 00:00:00" 
           AND Impressions.timestamp <= "2016-07-31 00:00:00"
   )
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an `INDEX` on `timestamp` column of `impressions` table. And see if improved else try using the created index in the query(forcing index).

**UPDATE**

Use `INDEX` in the `JOIN`

```
SELECT
DISTINCT (Personas.id),
Personas.parent_id, 
Personas.persona, 
Personas.subpersonas_count, 
Personas.is_subpersona, 
Personas.impressions_count, 
Personas.created, 
Personas.modified
FROM 
    personas as Personas 
INNER JOIN   
    impressions_personas ImpressionsPersonas ON (
    Personas.id = ImpressionsPersonas.persona_id
)
INNER JOIN 
    impressions Impressions WITH(INDEX(timestamp)) ON 
    (Impressions.id = ImpressionsPersonas.impression_id AND
    Impressions.timestamp >= "2016-06-01 00:00:00" AND 
    Impressions.timestamp <= "2016-07-31 11:59:59")
```

Comment: KEY `timestamp` (`timestamp`),

Answer (score 0):

At the moment you're first joining three tables with millions of rows and then using `DISTINCT` to get only a few rows out of it. Better way is to first get only the required IDs and then use those to select the actual result data.

For example:

```
SELECT column, other FROM personas
WHERE id IN
  (SELECT distinct persona_id
    FROM impressions_personas
    INNER JOIN impressions Impressions
      ON Impressions.id = ImpressionsPersonas.impression_id
        AND Impressions.timestamp >= "2016-06-01 00:00:00"
        AND Impressions.timestamp <= "2016-07-31 00:00:00"))
```

This way the engine will only handle a single column for the whole procedure until getting the results.